# Standalone Executable error: exe has stopped working: Made with Pyqt5 + Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I made an app with Pyqt, which I freezed with Pyinstaller with following options:- (Consider python file name as **pyqt_link6.py**)

```
pyi-makespec pyqt_link6.py
pyinstaller --noupx --debug pyqt_link6.spec
```

Resulting executable launches on my computer and several others (all Windows 7) and functions as expected. However on some machines (same Windows 7 version), it gives following problem:-

[image]

(pyqt_link6 is also name of directory where distribution is automatically stored by pyinstaller)

I thought adding `--debug` option during build was supposed to capture initialization process. But that is not happening.

My main problem is lack of indication of error. What should I look for to correct?
My Python version is 2.7.14 (Anaconda distribution), pyqt 5.6.0, pyinstaller 3.3.1.

I have intentionally not provided any more info, thinking that it may not be necessary and would be like spamming the forum. But should anything more (my python code or spec file be) posted here?. Any indication towards what the problem might be would be helpful.

As some machines can run exe and some can't; what difference should be looked at?

Regards,

Comment: To see the error output, package the app with `console=True` and then run the executable from the command line.

Comment: @MalloyDelacroix Where should that option go? On command line when building the app? Thanks.

Comment: @MalloyDelacroix Also, in spec file that option is already activated:- `exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='pyqt_link6',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )`

Comment: Sorry, I assumed since it was a PyQt app that you were building it in windowed mode so the command line would not display.  That option is True by default.

Comment: any luck with this? I have the same issue. When I set debug=True and console=True, I don't get any Traceback as to why it stopped. It also just stops randomly at different times within my GUI for me, and only one one PC (all running Win10).